# Data Access Patterns for Angular

Tags: angular, design-patterns, rxjs, observable, data-access

I'm struggling with asynchronous Data Access Patterns in an Angular 8 application (coming from .NET). I am using components, services for data access, and custom classes that act on the data from the services. It seems that I should inject my data access services into my components - but where do I leverage my custom classes for business logic?

What I'd like:

COMPONENT:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SampleService } from '../services/sample.service';
import { CustomBusinessLogic } from '../../cbl'; 


@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class Example implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  doSomething() {

    const dataToActOn = this.sampleService.getDataToActOn();

    // Do something with dataToActOn here

      const p = new CustomBusinessLogic.Calculator(
        dataToActOn.params as Settings,
        dataToActOn.data1,
        dataToActOn.data2
      );

      const res = p.calculate();
  }
}
```

SERVICE:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleDataService } from './data/example-data.service';
import { SettingsService } from './data/settings.service';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SampleService {

  data1: any[];
  data2: any[];
  params: [];

  constructor(private projections: ,
    private data: ExampleDataService, private settingsService: SettingsService) { }


  loadDataHttp() {

    const id = 'for-testing';
    const b = this.data.getDataSet1(new Date());
    const p = this.data.getDataSet2(new Date());
    const m = this.settingsService.getDataSet3(id, 2018);

    return forkJoin([b, p, m]);

  }

  getDataToActOn() {

    this.loadDataHttp().subscribe(data => {
      this.data1 = data[0];
      this.data2 = data[1];
      this.params = data[2];

      // HOW DO I RETURN THIS DATA TO THE COMPONENT 
      // AND HAVE IT AVAILABLE TO MY CUSTOM BUSINESS LOGIC??

    });
  }
}
```

My problem (in this pseudo/example code) is that when my Component gets to `new CustomBusinessLogic.Calculator`, none of the data has returned yet from the service.

How can I restructure this so that I can act on data returned from services in either my components or other services?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to learn how asynchrony and observables work. You don't subscribe in the service. You return an observable from the service, and you subscribe to it in the component (or in the view with the async pipe). Your service has no reason to have any property other than httpClient. The Angular documentation has entire chapters dedicated to that.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `Observable` in `getDataToActOn` function in your service.

So the function should be like the following.

```
getDataToActOn() {
    return this.loadDataHttp().pipe(map(data => ({
        data1: data[0],
        data2: data[1],
        params: data[2]
    })));
}
```

Check [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/reading-the-rxjs-6-sources-map-and-pipe-94d51fec71c2) if you would like to study deeply about RxJS `pipe` and `map`.

And then subscribe the data from your component with

```
this.sampleService.getDataToActOn().subscribe(dataToActOn => {

    const p = new CustomBusinessLogic.Calculator(
      dataToActOn.params as Settings,
      dataToActOn.data1,
      dataToActOn.data2
    );

    const res = p.calculate();

});
```

Comment: Your advice to return an observable is good, but your code doesn't return an observable.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
getDataToActOn() {
   this.loadDataHttp().subscribe(data => {
    this.data1 = data[0];
    this.data2 = data[1];
    this.params = data[2];
    // What now?
});
```

}

To this in the service:

```
getDataToActOn() {
   return this.loadDataHttp();
}
```

Also change this:

```
doSomething() {

    const dataToActOn = this.sampleService.getDataToActOn();

    // Do something with dataToActOn here

    const p = new CustomBusinessLogic.Calculator(
        dataToActOn.params as Settings,
        dataToActOn.data1,
        dataToActOn.data2
    );

   const res = p.calculate();
}
```

To this in the component:

```
doSomething() {
   this.sampleService.getDataToActOn().subscribe(
        (dataToActOn) => {
            const p = new CustomBusinessLogic.Calculator(
                dataToActOn.params as Settings,
                dataToActOn.data1,
                dataToActOn.data2
            );
            const res = p.calculate();
        }
    );
}
```

Sorry if the formatting is a bit screwed.

The getDataToActOn is now obviously a bit thin. You’d use that method to pass arguments, options and headers to the http service normally.